# Distance between two functions must be greater than 1

Tags: geometry, functions

The functions used for this problem are simplified functions:

I have a function $g(x)=x_1^2$ and I have a function $h(x,b)=x+b$ and the Area (let's say in the interval x=[0,5]) between these two functions should be minimized while

**constraint:** the line represented by the function $h(x)$ must always be a minimum of $1$ unit under/away from g(x).

So looking at the point x=[0,0], the value $b$ in function $h(x)$ must be smaller or equal to $-1$.

In now need to setup the constraint as a mathematical inequation $j(x,b)\leqq1$ but I don't really know how this is done. I only know that the function $j(x,y)$ needs to calculate the distance between the two functions and I already read on the internet about it but the people suggested that the distance is calculated like this:

$j(x,b)=|g(x)-h(x)|$

That doesn't really make sense for me since in this equation only the vertical distance is being considered. Does someone have any other suggestions (or clarifications)?

Comment: When you say "the line represented by the function h(x) must always be a minimum of 1 unit under/away from g(x)", do you mean pointwise distance or is there a way of measuring distance between two functions?

Comment: From the description you have given, $j \left( x, b \right) \geq 1$.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh I ment pointwise. Yes, you are right. Has to be "greater than" of course.

Comment: You use both "under" and "away" to describe the distance between the curves $y=g(x)$ and $y=h(x)$. But "under" specifically refers to vertical distance, so it is hardly surprising that people give you a vertical distance formula. And even more so, as you describe it as a distance between "functions", which is also measured vertically, instead of a distance between "curves". "Away" is less specific in its meaning, so adding it does not clarify the situation.